# Bitwise operation gives incorrect result

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

I'm fairly new to bitwise operations so I apologize ahead of time if my question seems poorly worded or not fit for stackoverflow. Recently, I've been toying with the bitwise AND operation by simply just printing out the results of expressions using the `&` symbol between binaries (in some expressions I use the bitwise AND between binaries and decimals). For example, I know that `110 & 4` equals `4` because `110 & 4` equates to `110 & 100` and

```
 1 1 0
 1 0 0
-------
 1 0 0
```

I get this result after printing it in C as well as inputting the values into a bitwise operation calculator. However, I get confused when certain equations like these arise,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%X\n", 010 & 2); //prints out 0?!?!?
    printf("%X\n", 10 & 2); //prints out 2
    printf("%X\n", 011 & 010); //prints out 8?!?!?
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why the first line of `main` prints out 0 because my understanding that `010` and `10` are the same binary (please correct me if I'm wrong) and `010 & 010` should equal `010` which equates to `2`. Lastly the last output completely throws me off guard because what I expected it to print out was,

```
 0 1 1
 0 1 0
-------
 0 1 0
```

However, the actual output is 8.

Lastly, I have one quick question about how these bitwise operations turn into booleans. For example, I've seen coders use these expressions as conditions in if statements such as

```
int byte;
scanf("%d",&byte);
if(byte & 2){
.....
}
```

Does `byte & 2` equate to true as long as the result isn't 0? Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I see why my question was unclear now, for I forgot to mention the type of integer constant I was working with. My intention was to use binaries rather than octals so I apologize for this confusion.

**EDIT2**: Now it seems that the above if statement isn't working when I input `0b010` into the console. However, `0b010 & 2` equates to 2 so what could be potentially causing this?

```
int byte;
scanf("%d",&byte);
if(byte & 2){
    //doesn't work when I input 0b010
}
if(0b010 & 2){
    //statement gets executed here but not the above, why?
}
```

Comment: `110` dec is `0b1101110`. And read how integer constants are written in C, that is shown in any halfway acceptable C book. Don't mix number systems without indicator, your question is not clear.

Comment: In what base are you trying to work? Seems like your left operand is binary and right is decimal?

Comment: In C (and some other languages) when you begin a number with `0` it means **octal**, not binary.

Comment: @Olaf my apologies, you're right in that I should have done research into how binaries are written in C.

Comment: @amit for some reason, my professor told me to write the expression to have a binary on the left and a decimal on the right, is this bad notation?

Comment: Well, the standard does not provide a syntax for binary constants. Only decimal, hex and octal. The common `0b` prefix is an extension of some compilers.

Comment: Also, to anyone who downvoted the question or has any critique about it, please leave suggestions on how I can improve. I've listented to some already by editing the question to make it clearer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you so much, this solved the issue in my edit!

Comment: I believe binary constants were added to official C++ in 2014, but are not officially in C (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C:

- `010` is octal for 8
- `10` is decimal for 10.
- `011` is octal for 9.

and, while we're at it ...

- `100` is decimal for 100.

If you want binary you need to do something different:

- Some compilers/standards accept `0b010` for binary constants.
- Otherwise you need to convert to decimal, octal (starting `0`), or hexadecimal (starting `0x`)

---

The answer to the second part is that bitwise operators do not "turn into booleans". C interprets any zero or null value as false, in an `if` statement, for example, and any non-zero value as true. In non boolean contexts they're just numbers, pointers, whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much for this was very helpful! I do have one question however. For some odd reason with the last snippet of code above in my question, when I input 0b010, the if statement condition does not evaluate to true. Yet I printed out the value of 0b010 & 2 in a separate program, and the value is greater than 0. What could be causing this oddity?

Comment: `scanf` probably does not support binary constants. It just sees the `0` followed by something that is not a number, and doesn't read any further.

Comment: I see, someone posted a comment earlier, which is now deleted for some reason, about taking the input in as a string and then parsing with `strol` which works.